# dartlang: how do you highlight table rows?

Tags: dart

I'm new to dart so this might seem like a silly question but I'd like to apply different CSS to different rows based on column values:

```
<table id="requests">
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Approved</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Denied</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Ipsum</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

So far I can do this:

```
queryAll("tr td").classes.add("foo");
```

But I'm wondering how to get all rows whose columns have the value "Approved".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick dirty way to do it from code:

```dart
  querySelectorAll('tr').where(
      (tr)=> tr.children.any(
         (td)=>td.text == 'Approved'
       )
  )
  .forEach((approvedTr)=>approvedTr.classes.add('approved'));
```

**But** i really recommend you to use a **databinding framework** (like *Polymer*, or *AngularDart*) to set different styles/classes depending on data. It's far more easy to use.

**[[A new thread was opened about doing this using Polymer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760797/dartlang-how-do-you-highlight-table-rows)**

Comment: querySelectorAll is actually deprecated so I changed it to use queryAll but still got this error "Uncaught Unsupported operation: td is not a template. "

Comment: I just tested my code and fixed it (*content* replaced by *text*), it now run fine, but i didn't get your error... :S

Comment: @jwesonga Where do you get the information that `querySelectorAll` is deprecated? `query` and `queryAll` are marked as deprecated but not `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll`.

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` is not deprecated. It's `queryAll()` that's deprecated, because its behavior will change to match the spec.

Comment: My mistake..seems I had fired up a rather old editor which was using some 0.X.X SDK..don't ask me how..

Comment: @Vloz any pointers on how I can translate this into polymer? I'd like it to have multiple conditions, so "Approved" should have approved css class, "Denied" .denied css class etc