# Dart-Polymer: Create a polymer element with varying css in each row

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'd like to build a polymer element consisting of table whose row CSS varies depending on the certain data, I got some help here to implement something similar in dart but I'm exploring the option of using a polymer element. The dart implementation had:

```dart
void highlightRows(){

  querySelectorAll('tr').where(
      (tr)=> tr.children.any(
               (td)=>td.text == 'Approved'
             )  
  ).forEach((approvedTr)=>approvedTr.classes.add('foo'));

}
```

Which only caters for rows that have "Approved" I'd like the polymer element to cater for rows that have "Denied" and "none". I'd appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
I updated the code with an example I just tried.
I use DartEditor dev channel and Polymer 0.10.0-pre.12
**EDIT END**

I didn't try the code but I think it should work.
You need some more Dart/HTML boilerplate to make a working Polymer element.
See https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/ to get started.

In the Polymer element you need a field that holds a collection with a value for each row.

**index.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample app</title>

    <!-- import the test-element -->

    <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="test_element.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TestPolymer</h1>

    <p>Sort observable</p>

    <test-element></test-element>

  </body>
</html>
```

**test_element.html**

```dart
<polymer-element name="test-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      tr.foo {
        background-color: #00ff00;
      }
    </style>
    <table>
      <tr template repeat="{{row in rows}}" class="{{ {'foo': row.contains('Approved')} }}">
        <td template repeat="{{cell in row}}">{{cell}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="test_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**test_element.dart**

```dart
library test_element;

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('test-element')
class PeopleElement extends PolymerElement {

  List<List<String>> rows = toObservable( // toObservable allows to update the HTML itself when the list content changes
  [
    ['Row1-cell1', 'Row1-cell1', 'Row1-cell3', 'Approved'],
    ['Row2-cell1', 'Approved', 'Row2-cell3', 'Row2-cell4'],
    ['Approved', 'Row3-cell2', 'Row3-cell3', 'Row3-cell4'],
    ['Row4-cell1', 'Row4-cell2', 'Row4-cell3', 'Row4-cell4']
  ]);

  PeopleElement.created() : super.created() {
    print('PeopleElement');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Moving this answer [from the previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760797/dartlang-how-do-you-highlight-table-rows) as an additional example of Gunter's answer]**

Here is an example using a Polymer-Element to show the table ([you can also use data-binding without creating a polymer element according to the doc](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#bindingoutside), but i dunno if it works with dart):

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<polymer-element name="myapp-request-table">
  <style>
  .Approved{
      background-color: green;
}

.Denied{
      background-color: red;
  }
  ...
  </style>

  <table id="requests">
      <template reapeat="{req in myRequestList}">
          <tr class="{{req.statut}}"> <!-- row class depends on request.statut value-->
              <td>{{req.title}}</td>
              <td>{{req.statut}}</td>
              <td>{{req.date}}</td>
          </tr>
      </template>
  </table>
</polymer-element>
```

To use this html, you need to provide a compliant **data context**.

In this example, *myRequestList* is a List of a specific **model** object set in the polymer-element code like this:

```dart
@CustomTag('myapp-request-table')
class MyAppRequestTable extends PolymerElement{

@observable ObservableList<MyRequestClass> myRequestList = new ObservableList<MyRequestClass>(); //here is the data context

MyAppRequestTable.created() :  super.created(){
     myRequestList.addAll([new MyRequestClass('foo','denied',new DateTime.now()), new MyRequestClass('42','approved',new DateTime.now())]); //filling the data-context once the element is created
 }

}


class MyRequestClass extends Observable {

  @observable String title;

  @observable String statut;

  @observable DateTime date;

  MyRequestClass(this.title,this.statut,this.date);

}
```

Then you juste have to import the custom element anywhere you want, and set its data context from outside.